# Laravel: Get variable name from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I get the name of the get variable from a route url?

```
http://localhost:8000/api/system/123
```

Basically I want to know what the GET variable is called that holds the value of `123`. For example here it is called `id`

```
http://localhost:8000/api/system?id=123
```

How can this be done?

```
Route::get('api/system/{id}', 'ApiController@User');
```

Comment: Yes, that is how you would get it from the route. You'd pass `$id` into the construction of your function `public function User($id)`

Comment: I have tried it and http://localhost:8000/api/system?id=123 returns page not found and i can change {id} to anything i want without changing anything else and it still works..

Answer (score 0):

The route variable is injected in your method.
Laravel takes care of the injection for you, you can read more details about [IOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container)

```
class ApiController{

    public function User($id)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    class ApiController extends Controller{

        public function User($id)
        {
           dd($id)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The route must be defined as:

```
Route::get('api/system', 'ApiController@user');
```

And in your controller to get the value of any variable should be:

```
public function user(Request $request){
  dd($request->get('id'));
}
```

### Recommendations

- If you are only going to receive an id use

  Route::get('api/system/{id}, 'ApiController@user');

And the controller should be:

```
public function user($id){
  dd($id);
}
```

- The methods in the controller should be down cased. Ex: user instead of User
- Read this [laravel routes documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)